# NestedScrollView having ConstraintLayout as Child is not working,

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have an xml,NestedScrollView with constraintlayout as child layout. scroll is not working.I tried setting fillviewport as true, still its not working. Constraint layout only with recyclerview is working as expected. But if I tried using NestedScrollView with Constraint layout, scroll is not working.

Requirement is the whole page should scroll.
Can someone help  me?

Here is my xml

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlayout_generic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
            android:padding="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_wallet_title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textview_wallet_total_price" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_wallet_total_price"
            style="@style/Regular.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:text="₹ 0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_wallet_title"
            style="@style/Regular.Caption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/lbl_wallet_tilte"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_wallet_total_price" />
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_transaction_title"
            style="@style/Regular.Subheading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/lbl_transaction_history"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_wallet_title" />
        
       
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_wallet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/content_edge_margin_horizontal"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_transaction_title" />
    
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_wallet_history"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textview_transaction_title"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Set the height of the child of the ScrollView (ConstraintLayout) to wrap_content.

Comment: I tried but the result is same. Scroll is  not happening

Comment: Try it this way: Put a RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout as the root layout and put your NestedScrollView underneath.